# How do I use email as name identifier format in SAML 2.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, saml-2.0

I currently have the following setting in my SAML 2.0 config:

```
# config/devise.rb
settings.name_identifier_format = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient"
```

Using [devise_saml_authenticatable](https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml/blob/37368619bf04cfccad9634e79c98e5b9b38d980d/lib/onelogin/ruby-saml/authrequest.rb#L118) gem, this renders into:

```
<samlp:NameIDPolicy
  AllowCreate='true'
  Format='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent' />
```

which returns a name_id like the following:

```
<saml:NameID
  Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient"
  NameQualifier="http://idp.ssocircle.com">
  lfYRV6q2qqNKhBaEe7F3qzvCacKP
</saml:NameID>
```

I'd like to use `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent` so that it returns the email address and name_id. But I am getting an error my IDP (SSOCircle). Are there additional configs that I should set up?

```
# config/devise.rb
settings.name_identifier_format = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent"
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the implementation of [authenticate_with_saml](https://github.com/apokalipto/devise_saml_authenticatable/blob/e6a7e9c55614a13b0d99a72aefae9fc7a73167e9/lib/devise_saml_authenticatable/model.rb#L50) and it actually looks for the email attribute if Devise.saml_use_subject is set to false.

```
if (Devise.saml_use_subject)
  auth_value = saml_response.name_id
else
  inv_attr = attribute_map.invert
  auth_value = attributes[inv_attr[key.to_s]]
  auth_value.try(:downcase!) if Devise.case_insensitive_keys.include?(key)
end
```

Alli had to do was to change the devise setting `saml_use_subject` to

```
# config/devise.rb
config.saml_use_subject = false
```